# How to install and configure vee-validate (v4) in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm having a hard time understanding the docs to install this awesome plugin in to nuxt. From what I understand, which I find hard to believe, you have to export all of the rules in a plugin file. I tried to export some of the rules, but nuxt didn't know what the ValidationObserver component was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VeeValidate v4 is not compatible with Vue 2.x, and that means it won't work with Nuxt 2.x as vee-validate (v4) is only targeting Vue 3 support.

Generally, with vee-validate v3 you do need to register your rules in a plugin file, and register the `validation-observer` and `validation-provider` globally or import them when needed.

Comment: Also not when using the nuxt-composition-api?

Comment: Nope, it relies on the new reactivity system only present in Vue 3

Answer (score 5):

I installed vee-validate v3 into Nuxt by doing the following:

`npm install --save vee-validate`

Add this to 'plugins' section in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vee-validate.js', ssr: true },
],
```

Add this to 'build' section in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
build: {
    transpile: ['vee-validate']
}
```

The transpile section is required to get rid of an error about `Unexpected token 'export'`. It does something related to ES6 and Babel to perhaps pre-transpile the library before loading it into Nuxt.

Here is what my `vee-validate.js` file looks like in the plugins directory:

```
import { extend, localize } from "vee-validate";
import { required, email, min } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

const dictionary = {
    en: {
        messages: {
            required: () => '* Required',
        },
    },
};

// Install required rule.
extend("required", required);

// Install email rule.
extend("email", email);

// Install min rule.
extend("min", min);

localize(dictionary);
```

Comment: If I use the development server `yarn dev`, my validation works. However, in static site generator mode uing `yarn generate or npm run generate` the validation is gone. Even with `ssr:true`. The strange thing is that I tried to deploy with Gitlab pages, and it works. However, copying the public folder in other hosting server doesn't work. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding this to your nuxt.config.js file: build: {
        transpile: ['vee-validate'],
}

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Neither ` build: { transpile: ['vee-validate'], }` nor ` build: { transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules'], }` works. I created a plugin for it in $PROJECT_DIR/plugins/vee_validate.js.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do

Comment: do you maybe have a project reference or Github repo that uses vee-validate for the static site deployment?

Comment: I don't have a public one sorry